# Is there a way to copy Javascript Iterator or get IteratorIndex Value

Tags: javascript, iterator

I need to implement an algorithm with backtracking. For that I need to store an iterator value somehow, and restore it when I need to backtrack.

But I see no other way but to convert `Map`s and `Set`s into `Array`s.

And I can see `IteratorIndex`

```
SetIterator {1, 2}
  [[Entries]]
    0: 1
    1: 2
  __proto__: Set Iterator
  [[IteratorHasMore]]: true
  [[IteratorIndex]]: 0
  [[IteratorKind]]: "values"
```

in the console, but do not know how to access it.

I need something like this:

```js
function f1(iter) {
  // ...
  iter.next()
  // ...
  const error = true
  return ! error
}
function f2(iter) {
  // ...
  iter.next()
  // ...
  const error = false
  return ! error
}

function f0(iter) {
  const current_iter = iter
    // trying to remember iterator's current position
    // it doesn't work, obviously. Instead I need something like
    // const current_iter = iter.copy()

  if( f1(iter) ) return true
    // f1() returns with an error, I need to backtrack

  iter = current_iter
    // trying to restore iterator's position after it was moved inside of f1()

  if( f2(iter) ) return true

  return false
}

const data = new Set([1,2,3,4])
const iter = data.values()
// ...
iter.next() // iterator is moved somewhere
// ...
f0(iter)
console.log(iter.next().value) // should be 3 but it's 4
```

Am I missing something, or is there any good reason not to allow Iterators' copies in JS?

Comment: do you have an example of working code?

Comment: @NinaScholz What do you mean? I need a copy of an iterator. I can't get it. Hence, there is no working code

Comment: please add the part which is not working.

Comment: @NinaScholz added

Comment: it looks like you need a caching function/wrapper. or a double linked list.

Comment: As far as “is there any good reason not to allow Iterators' copies in JS?”, not all iterators are copyable. I agree this is missing from `Map` and `Set` iterators, though.

Comment: @NinaScholz, `Array`'s are good enough. No need for linked lists that are not native to JS. But that's exactly the problem: **I can** use other structures, but I **don't want to** convert `Map`s and `Set`s (as they are given to me, and I'm trying not to copy possibly huge collections). As for caching... I'm missing the point: what should I cache?

Comment: @Ry- Well, it's not like there is an assortment of `Iterator`s in *JS*, like it is in *C++* One definitely can create a copyable iterator. And yea, this actually hunted me for years. I miss them much! :)